# Asynchronous tasks are not done in play framework(scala)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have some code that i want to run asynchronously in a request. That code has no effect on the response so i run it like this

```
import scala.concurrent.Future    

Database.forURL(url, driver = driver) withSession {
  implicit session =>
// some db changes
//some code that has effect on response like getting userId
//so run synchronously

// now asynchronous code

import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

Future {
          println("inside Futute, starting")
          val userAuthTable = TableQuery[Tables.UserAuth]
          println("inside Futute, running")
          // some db operations
          println("inside Futute, done")

} // Future block ends
userId


} // session ends
```

Here i can see the 2 lines print on the console

```
inside Futute, starting
```

and

```
inside Futute, running
```

but i dont see

```
inside Futute, done
```

Neither the `db operations` are done. I am able to get `userId` which is outside `Future`. When i put those db operations outside the `Future`, they get executed. But why not inside the `Future`? And why the first 2 lines get printed on the console. I am using `play 2.3.3` and scala `2.11`.

**Update**

My code was in a Postgres Session and somehow `Future` block gets executed outside of scope of session. So i created 2 sessions, one for executing the `db code` synchronously and the other for asynchronous code inside the `Future`. This works correctly

```
import scala.concurrent.Future    

val userId = Database.forURL(url, driver = driver) withSession {
    implicit session =>
    // some db changes
    //some code that has effect on response like getting userId
    //so run synchronously
} // session ends

// now asynchronous code
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

Future {
println("inside Futute, starting")
Database.forURL(url, driver = driver) withSession {
   implicit session =>
      val userAuthTable = TableQuery[Tables.UserAuth]
      println("inside Futute, running")
      // some db operations
   } // session ends
      println("inside Futute, done")
} // Future ends
```

Thanks to @Ryan and @applicius

Comment: Where is the code executing the `Future`?

Comment: Executing the `Future`? Do i need to execute it? I thought you just put the code inside `Future` block that you need to run. Sorry. I am new to Scala. I just now put a `()` after the ending brace of `Future` and it gives `Not applicable error`. But if the future was not executed why did the 1st 2 lines print?

Comment: @applicius How can i execute the `Future`?

Comment: Try [Await](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$).result .

Comment: @applicius But wouldnt that be blocking. I dont want to block because i dont care when that code completes execution. And any ideas on why only some part of that code is getting executed?

Comment: If it work like that it means it doesn't come from operations wrapped in the Future (but from the context which is killed before end), if it doesn't work you have your answer.

Comment: @applicius You don't need to wait on a future to execute it.
@lovesh add a `.recover` on your future to make sure it's completing without an exception.  Could be that an exception is being thrown in the Future block.

Comment: @Ryan you don't need to wait, but spawning a Future like that you have no garantee if the parent thread/process go to end.

Comment: @Ryan I ran the code with a `recover` like this `.recover { case e: Exception => println(e.getMessage()) }` and it gave an exception message `This connection has been closed.`. I am running the future inside a `Postgres Session`. I have updated my code.

Comment: @Ryan you can answer the question so i can mark it accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `.recover` to the end of your future to make sure an exception isn't being thrown and ignored.